# CSS media query 'prefers-reduced-motion' breaks bootstrap 4 animations in Firefox on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, bootstrap-4, media-queries, ubuntu-18.04

I do some frontend development on Ubuntu with Bootstrap 4 and Firefox 65. Some animations don't work because of rules like that in bootstrap.css:

```
@media screen and (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
    .carousel-item {
        transition: none
    }
}
```

It looks like Ubuntu prefers to reduce motion. How can I disable that? Thanks.

Comment: For anyone who views this in the future: this is not a bug, it's a feature.

The CSS is behaving exactly the way it should based on the user's specific preference of NOT seeing animations, and the "fix" below is not appropriate given the user's stated preferences.

Comment: https://developer.paciellogroup.com/blog/2019/05/short-note-on-prefers-reduced-motion-and-puzzled-windows-users/ - a good read

Answer (score 4):

This is a new CSS feature that web browsers will respect from now on. Can read more about this here: [Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/03/prefers-reduced-motion)

Had faced this problem once. The closest solution I could find is to override the bootstrap css

```
`@media screen and (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce){
  .fade {
    transition: none;
  }
}`
```

with this one :

```
`@media screen and (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce){
  .fade {
    transition: opacity .15s linear!important;
  }
}`
```

It brings the fade effect back. but not quite smooth as before.

Comment: I went for the slightly simpler: `@media (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) { .fade { transition: opacity 0.15s linear; } }`

Comment: Yes, the word `screen` is not necessary. And as you know `!important` is for just in case...